# Unable to pass workflow input variable as input to action

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm running some Ansible playbooks from a self hosted runner to deploy websites and need to send the results via email. I'm using a manually triggered workflow_dispatch event with one custom user input argument to start everything and the dawidd6/action-send-mail@v3 action to send the email (https://github.com/marketplace/actions/send-email).

I able to access the argument from user input in the first step that runs the Ansible playbooks, but not in the next step to send the email. The Ansible playbooks run and the email sends successfully, but I can't get the specific user supplied variable into the email.

I've tried accessing it directly in the github.event.inputs. context, which works in the Ansible playbooks step, saving that to a variable and accessing that, passing it to an environment variable in the first step and referencing that in the email step, and passing it to an HTML file in the first step and referencing that, all of which failed.

My sanitized Github action code:

```
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      site_name:
        description: 'Site hostname'
        required: true
        default: 'dev.llamasrkewl.com'
        type: text

jobs:
  deploy_new_website:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
      - run: |
          site_name="${{ github.event.inputs.site_name }}"
          ansible-playbook playbook1.yml -e "site_name=$site_name"
          ansible-playbook playbook2.yml -e "site_name=$site_name"
          ansible-playbook playbook3.yml -e "site_name=$site_name"
        id: site_deployment
        shell: bash
      - name: Send mail
        if: always()
        uses: dawidd6/action-send-mail@v3
        with:
          server_address: smtp_server.mydomain.com
          subject: ${{ github.repository }} deployment status ${{ job.status }}
          to: me.mydomain.com
          from: repo@mydomain.com
          body: [??? $site_name? ${{ github.event.inputs.site_name }}? other?] has status of ${{ job.status }}
```

I will personally send an actual live llama to anyone who can help me solve this (optional).

Comment: Have you tried quoting the body? `body: '${{ inputs.site_name }} has status of ${{ job.status }}'`

Comment: @aknosis yes I tried that, good thought though, thank you.

Comment: Are you getting the raw string in your email `${{ github.event.inputs.site_name }}` or is it a blank space?

Comment: When I tried to save that value to a variable named $site_name and use that, I got the literal "$site_name" in my email.

If I try to reference ${{ github.event.inputs.site_name }} directly, with our without double quotes, the GitHub editor throws up an error, "can not read an implicit mapping pair; a colon is missed" and if I save it the action will fail to run. It seems like the mail action isn't able to use the inputs variable I'm thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minor issue that is not easy to figure out: change your input type from `text` to `string`.

```
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      site_name:
        description: 'Site hostname'
        required: true
        default: 'dev.llamasrkewl.com'
        type: string
```

The only valid values for type are [boolean, number, or string](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onworkflow_callinputsinput_idtype)

Comment: OMG THAT WAS IT!!! After changing the type to `string` I was able to reference the variable using `${{ github.event.inputs.site_name }}` without quotes in the subject and body of the email and it worked as expected.  

Strange that it worked fine in my first step with the type set wrong. I wish the documentation would mention the valid types in the on.workflow_dispatch.inputs section too, I didn't notice that part in the on.workflow_call.inputs section above, although I see now dispatch is a subset of those.  

Thank you so much!!! Let me know where to send the llama.

Comment: This is a syntax validation issue, it appears that the `with:` map checks the type on the values. In your first use of `site_name` there is no validation on the type so that step runs without issue.